# Angular "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"

Tags: angularjs, typescript

im new in angular and typescript. I made a little program about adding two numbers, but when I run it on the browser an error appears in the console "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :". I dont know what I am doing wrong. Any ideas?

```
var add = (x: number, y: number) => {
    return x + y;
};

let res = add(2, 5);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Browser dont support typescript, thus error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browser dont support typescript, thus it errored out. Below is the code without typescript. Typescript code need to be compiled to JS to run in browser.

```
var add = (x, y) => {
    return x + y;
};

let res = add(2, 5);

console.log(res);
```